# What is causing the message "Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so" ("No such file or directory")?

Tags: php, xdebug, ini

When I run `php --version` (on CentOS release 6.4), I get:

```
# php --version
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP 5.4.19 (cli) (built: Aug 22 2013 08:03:53)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

What is the source of the "Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" message?

I confirmed the location of my php.ini file using:

```
# php -a
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Interactive shell

php > echo php_ini_loaded_file() . "\n";
/etc/php.ini
```

And then I searched /etc/php.ini for "/usr/lib":

```
# fgrep "/usr/lib" /etc/php.ini
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
```

PHP doesn't seem to be configured (in the php.ini) to look for xdebug.so in /usr/lib/php/modules/. So why am I getting that error message?

**Update:** In response to [Sverri M. Olsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300892/sverri-m-olsen)'s comment suggesting the path to xdebug.so might need fixing, I did:

```
# fgrep "xdebug" /etc/php.ini
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=vmhostmachine
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/usr/xdebug
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_format=1
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/usr/xdebug
xdebug.trace_output_name=trace.%H.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_name=profile.%H.%t
```

And I confirmed the above path to xdebug.so is correct:

```
# ls -lh /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200K May 21  2013 /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
```

Note also that Xdebug works.

Comment: If you're using apache, maybe there is a `LoadModule` for this path in the `httpd.conf`?

Comment: What does `cd /usr/lib/php/modules/; ls | grep "xdebug"` output?

Comment: @Bigood `fgrep "xdebug" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, `fgrep "php" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` return nothing.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen `ls /usr/lib/php` returns "ls: cannot access /usr/lib/php: No such file or directory"

Comment: @DarylSpitzer Okay. Seeing as the `php` binary seems to work you can find the extension directory like so: `php -i | grep "extension_dir"`. Go to that directory and `ls | grep "xdebug"`. If it finds nothing then you need to install it (or point to its correct location in `php.ini`).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen `php -i | grep "extension_dir"` returns "extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules" (and "sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value")

Comment: @DarylSpitzer In that case then it looks like `php.ini` is pointing at the wrong file. Open `php.ini`, go down until you see a bunch of `extension=*.so`, and then fix the path to `xdebug.so` (probably something like `/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so`). If `xdebug.so` is not found then it is probably not installed.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen See my question (towards the end) where I fgrep for "/usr/lib" in /etc/php.ini. I'll update the question with the results of `fgrep xdebug /etc/php.ini`.

Comment: Is this a Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS system? Do you have a directory `/etc/php.d`? If so, look in there for an included .ini file related to xdebug. In Red Hat derivative systems, `/etc/php.d` holds extension-specific .ini files which get included separately.

Comment: That was it @MichaelBerkowski. Turn your comment into an answer and you'll get the bounty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In GNU/Linux systems derived from modern Red Hat releases (such as RHEL, Fedora, and CentOS), the PHP distribution may be divided into the primary .ini file residing at `/etc/php.ini` as well as a collection of other .ini files specific to extensions or packages installed as RPMs residing in `/etc/php.d`.  At initialization, PHP will read `/etc/php.d/*.ini` after loading the main `php.ini` file.

It would seem that you have a stale file containing Xdebug settings residing in `/etc/php.d`. Grep for Xdebug in `/etc/php.d` to find the offender and remove it or comment out the relevant lines.

```bash
grep xdebug /etc/php.d/*.ini
```

If Xdebug was installed separately by a manual process and you manually modified the main `/etc/php.ini` to load the extension and configure its settings, that would explain why Xdebug otherwise works while you still see errors about its nonexistence at `/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so`.  This also could have happened if configuration files from `/etc` were copied from an old 32bit system to a 64bit system wherein modules reside at `/usr/lib64/php/modules`